# check if a string has superscript character in it using javascript

Tags: javascript, unicode, superscript

I want to check if or not a string has superscript characters. I am actually reading a pdf file, and I want to check whether the read string has some superscript characters in it.

Answer (score 2):

If the superscripts and subscripts are done with Unicode rather than PDF markup, most of the codepoints you want are likely in the block `\u2070`-`\u2090`, plus a couple of extras:

```
var subscripts = /[\u2070-\u209F\u00B2\u00B3\u00B9]/;
var target = "foo¹";
target.match(subscripts);
```

output:

```
[ '¹', index: 3, input: 'foo¹' ]
```